# Android: Presenting Sqlite database data in GraphView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, graph

I want to display the results entered into my database graphically, 
and whenever i run the program, and enter x and y values, they dont plot properly at all, and the graph makes no sense essentially.

Eventually i plan to implement this very basic project into another larger one im developing, i just want to get this one working as a starting point.

Here is the code i have used:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
GraphView graph;
Button button;
EditText xInput, yInput;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
MyHelper myHelper;
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    xInput= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editX);
    yInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editY);
    graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);

    myHelper =new MyHelper(this);
    sqLiteDatabase = myHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    exqButton();
}

private void exqButton() {
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int xVal = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(yInput.getText()));
            int yVal = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(xInput.getText()));

            myHelper.insertData(xVal,yVal);
            series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(getData());
            graph.addSeries((series));
        }
    });


}

private DataPoint[] getData() {

    //read data from db

    String[] columns = {"xValues", "yValues"};
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query("MyTable", columns, null, null, null,null,null,null);
    DataPoint[] dp = new DataPoint[cursor.getCount()];
    for(int i = 0;i<cursor.getCount(); i++){
        cursor.moveToNext();
        dp[i]=new DataPoint(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getInt(1));

    }

    return dp;
}
```

Here is the database class:

```
public class MyHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private Context con;
public MyHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "MyDatabase",null,1);
    con = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String createTable="create table MyTable (xValues INTEGER, yValues INTEGER);";
    db.execSQL(createTable);
    Toast.makeText(con,"Table created",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public void insertData(int x, int y){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues= new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put("xValues", x);

    contentValues.put("yValues", y);

    db.insert("MyTable",null,contentValues);
    Toast.makeText(con, "data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Finally the layout:

```
<com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/graph"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="x"
    android:id="@+id/editX"/>

<Button
    android:text="Plot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="54dp"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="y"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText3"
    android:id="@+id/editY"/>
```

Im relatively new to this so wouldnt be surprised if its something obvious im missing, any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess the problem from what you have said.

> they dont plot properly at all, and the graph makes no sense
>   essentially.

If I were you, I would do these steps.
1. Database and table is properly created or not.
2. Table insert is working fine or not.
3. Querying x, y values returning proper values are not.
4. Print the values before you plotting in the graph.
5. Then finally check - Have you implemented graph API just fine or not.

One of the key things in programming is **debugging**
Use logger or system.out.println statements to figure out any problems in Android.

Good luck.